# Angular: xhrRequest do not send

Tags: angular, typescript

i got a service with a function for an http post request. For some reason the request is not sent. However, when I apply a subscription to the post, the request is executed.

In other services with identical structure have no problems to send a request in the same way without subscription.

What is the reason ?

```
export interface iChatbox {
  user: number;
  input: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class GlobalChatboxService {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  pushMessage(data: iChatbox): Observable<iChatbox> {
    return this.http.post<iChatbox>(
      `${environment.apiEndpoint}/chatbox/message/send`,
      data
    );
  }
}
```

This one works:

```
  pushMessage(data: iChatbox): Subscription {
    return this.http
      .post<iChatbox>(`${environment.apiEndpoint}/chatbox/message/send`, data)
      .subscribe();
  }
```

This also works

```
  signin(user: UserAuthData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiEndpoint}/login`, user);
  }
```

Comment: Are you actually subscribing to the observable?

Comment: @R.Richards hm i dont think so.. can you give a code explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Observables` are lazy you need to manually subscribe to fire them. They will remain awake until you tell them to stop broadcasting values. Http verbs in Angular are powered by `RxJS` under the hood. That's why the return type is an observable. Subscribe either in service or in consumer components. That depends on your business need.